# Saving files in Azure hosted website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, iis-7

We are currently hosting MVC webapp in IIS server. And we have option for end users to upload image/ pdf files. To store them we can use code some thing like this..

```
if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Images"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }
```

Now we have plans of hosting this on Azure. 
Will the above file storing mechanism work if we host in Azure? Or do we need to 
make changes in file storing mechanism(As Azure file system is different).

Answer (score 2):

How you deploy to Azure is up to you, and there are many ways you can do it (I'm not going to suggest any particular way). Objectively though:

**Virtual Machines**

- Virtual Machine OS disks are *durable*, stored in a page blob. However, this storage is not shared between VMs.
- Virtual Machine scratch disks (whether regular or SSD) are not durable. Assume data will be lost.
- You may attach durable disks to a Virtual Machine (each up to 1TB, up to two disks per core). These are blob-backed just like the OS disk. But again, not shared between Virtual Machine instances

**Cloud Services**

- Web and Worker role instances use non-durable OS disks.
- You may attach disks to web/worker roles (Azure Drives). These are durable and blob-backed. Not shared between instances.

**Web Apps**

- Web Apps provide durable storage (quantity based on app tier). This storage is shared with all instances of that web app. However, this storage goes away if you delete your web app.

**Azure Storage**

- You may choose to read/write from/to discrete blobs (each up to 200GB). These are independent of any VM/cloud service/web app. These are accessed via REST API (and wrapped with SDKs in numerous languages). Blobs do not map to local file directories (with the exception of page blobs, which *do* mount as a VHD, as mentioned in Virtual Machines above). Azure Storage provides up to 500TB per account, and you may have multiple storage accounts.
- Azure File Storage is an SMB share backed by Azure Storage (blobs). This is durable storage. You may mount this to your Virtual Machines (unlike Azure Disks, you may mount this to multiple VMs simultaneously). Azure File Storage provides up to 5TB per file share.
- For performance-oriented workloads, you may choose Premium Storage (SSD). Premium Storage disks are only compatible with specific Virtual Machine types, and are available in 128GB, 512GB, and 1TB capacities.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going with an azure VM and hosting the site in the IIS of that server then the approach will be same. You will have a persistent disk and the files can be stored there. but it is not a feasible solution if you have more files are getting uploaded and so on.

If you are going with azure app service web apps or web roles then this option is not feasible as storage in that instance will be limited and if the instance recycles or restarts in the case of webroles and deleted in the case of web apps that data will be gone.

Azure storage provides blob storage which is useful in storing binary files like documents, images, videos etc. Azure storage is cheap and it is highly available and reliable.

In your asp.net MVC app you have to add the azure storage SDK as a nuget reference and then use the upload/ download methods mentioned.

You can use azure blob storage if you are hosting your website in a VM as well.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/

http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2016/01/26/creating-a-photo-album-for-asp-net-mvc-5-users-using-azure-blob-storage.aspx

Comment: Your comments about Web Apps is incorrect - storage is durable unless the web app is actually deleted.